# Used and Cached Memory In Spark

Tags: apache-spark, caching, memory

I would like to know if spark uses the linux cached memory or the linux used memory when we use the cache/persist method.

I'm asking this because I we have a custer and we see that the machines are used only at 50% used memory and 50% cached memory even when we have long jobs.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Cached/buffered memory is memory that Linux uses for disk caching. When you read a file it is always read into memory cache. You can consider **cached** memory as free memory. JVM process of spark executor doesn't take directly **cached** memory. If you see that only 50% of memory is used on your machine, it means that spark executor definitely doesn't take more than 50% of memory. You can use `top` or `ps` utils to see how much memory spark executor actually takes. Usually it is a little bit more than current size of heap.